# Disable opcache in php command line

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm using `Apache 2.2.4` and `PHP 7.2.4` in Centos 7.4. 
PHP works as a module in apache (it's not php-fpm). 
All works well, but I would like to disable `opcache` when I execute php script from Linux Command line.

`phpinfo();` and `php -i` indicate to `/etc/php.ini`

Does somebody know how to resolve my problem?

Comment: [`opcache.enable_cli`](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.enable-cli) can be set to zero (although this is the default, so if you previously set it to true it then presumably you already know this?). What problem is this actually causing? Whether opcache is enabled or not generally won't have any effect on the CLI, since the process finishes along with the running script, and any cached scripts are lost anyway.

Comment: Also, if your running the CLI version, it is not running under Apache.

Comment: Thank You for answers. I didn't notice that opcache.enable.cli is disabled. But anyway, how to manipulate php options for CLI and don't affect a website PHP ?